# How can one find out whether Android is throttling my CPU, e.g. because the temperature is too high?

Tags: android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-9, cpu

I'm suspecting that Android sometimes limits my CPU at around 66% when the temperature is too high.

[image]

[image]

I can see that my Geekbench score is much lower than what it should be:

[image]

Even though my CPU isn't supposed to be throttled:

[image]

How can one find out whether Android is limiting my CPU, e.g. because the temperature is too high?

I use a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10.

Comment: Don't you think it's throttled because of low battery? ;)

Comment: @alecxs good point, though typically the device is slow when warm: cooling it down in a freezer seems to help make it go faster. But I'd definitely would be interesting to know if Android throttles the CPUs in case of low battery.

Comment: yes definitely. How to proof? I don't know https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241908